# What does 兼 mean when it appears next to a person's name in an organizational chart?

Tags: kanji

The 兼 character appears next to some people's names in the organizational chart of the company I work at, as shown below.

> 田中 太郎 （兼）

What meaning does the 兼 character signify in this context?

Comment: Should mean, that he 'too'/'also' is something. Is there something like a job description in before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

兼 in a labor chart means the person is 兼任 -- as in their official job is different, but this is being made one of their assignments as well.

For instance, I work for the 国際課 at my university, but I'm a 兼 assigned to teach an English class for the English department.

Comment: Do you mean to say 兼任?  兼業 often involves two whole different industries.

Comment: @l'électeur No, I'm just genuinely wrong. I had an issue earlier where my school was claiming it would be 兼業 for me to do a 講義 at a different school... Apparently, I have yet to master the usage. (But mistakes are how we learn!!!)

Comment: That would be a hard one to name.  兼業 is like a double-job situation and is perhaps most often used to describe a farmer who also does a completely different type of job besides farming.